# How do I parse this Flickr response?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, flickr

I get this from a sample Flickr response in their api site:

```
jsonFlickrApi({"method":{"_content":"flickr.test.echo"}, "format":{"_content":"json"}, "api_key":{"_content":"8038f7f7d7151ccbf6df2aa10b1b35ae"}, "stat":"ok"})
```

I can see the dictionary in there, right after the words jsonFlickApi.  But how do I get rid of that leading text and put the dictionary into my NSDictionary?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`NSJSONSerialization` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the JSON data.

**Edit:** The `jsonFlickrApi(...)` indicates that you're using a JSONP endpoint to talk to Flickr. You don't need this; a plain JSON endpoint is fine. According to [this Flickr API documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) you can fix this by including the parameter `nojsoncallback` with the value `1` when you make your request.

Comment: but will that get rid of the leading string?