# Calling Flickr API with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, flickr

I was trying to get some JSON data from a Flickr API but my Swift code is not working. 
This is based on [Jameson Quave's tutorial](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-tutorial-part-2/) on making an API request with Swift

```
func GetFlickrData(tags: String) {
   
    let baseURL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.search"
    let apiString = "&api_key=\(apiKey)"
    let searchString = "&tags=\(tags)"
    
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: baseURL + apiString + searchString)   
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(requestURL, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        
        var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            println(result)
        })
    })
    
    task.resume()
}
```

This shows me an error for the `requestURL` *argument* that says:

> "Vaue of type NSURL? not unwrapped".

When I add "!", the error goes away. But, I still get a runtime error when making the call. 
In the debugger, I see:

**data = (NSData!)16642 bytes**

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I missing?

**EDIT** - *This was working fine on Xcode 6, it broke when updating Xcode to version 6.1*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result variable actually is of type NSDictionary? and will raise a runtime error if it is nil and you try to access it.
The JSONObjectWithData function returns an optional as you can see in it's declaration:

```
class func JSONObjectWithData(data: NSData, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions, error: NSErrorPointer) -> AnyObject?
```

You have to cast the result in an object of type NSDictionary? and not NSDictionary in order to make it work

```
let result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary?
if let unwrappedResult = result {
    println(unwrappedResult)
}
```

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 2:**

JSONObjectWithData no longer returns an Optional but instead makes use of the new error handling and is marked as throwing. The signature now looks like this:

```
public class func JSONObjectWithData(data: NSData, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions) throws -> AnyObject
```

To achieve the same one would now have to wrap the call inside a do/catch block or alternatively use try? instead of try:

```
do {
    let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Ok, that fixed the runtime error. However, unwrappedResult is printing a nil. When I use the same URL in a browser, it gives me the JSON data I need.....but it looks like the JSONObjectWithData method is returning a nil. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to tell the API in wich format you would like the response to be. This can be done by sending a "format" parameter with a value of "json". I had some problems because even then the API responds with JSONP, but I found a solution here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930932/how-do-i-parse-this-flickr-response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930932/how-do-i-parse-this-flickr-response).

Comment: &nojsoncallback=1 is clutch!